# Finding Azure Servicebus Rogue Subscription Consumer

Tags: logging, ip-address, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I've got a very weird problem on our development environment. Some of our developers have created some workers to test out code that connects to an azure servicebus topic subscription consuming the incoming events.

However, after cleaning up all their services in the playground (it's pods in kubernetes on an AKS cluster), it seems there is still some process listening to the subscription and consuming incoming events.

I've already verified that all pods are gone, even drained the nodes to makes sure no ghost pods still linger.

I honestly thought it was easier to find the rogue process consuming the subscription, so I went to the portal to check if there are some logs with maybe a source ip so I could pinpoint the consuming process. Unfortunately there is no such thing (I couldn't find something that would help me).

Of course I can just simply rename the subscription but the metrics still show incoming requests to the service bus.

Anyone know of a way I can pinpoint a source ip of services connecting to an azure servicebus topic subscription?

Comment: Currently, not possible to trace what clients are connected. Saying that, you could connect with Azure support to find out.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. They couldn't help me any further either. We resolved the issue simply by renewing the authentication key.